# Sum a column in a loop....assigning

Tags: abap

I´m trying to sum all the values from a column which is in a internal table.
I have the following:

```
DATA: t2 TYPE TABLE OF komlfp.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <t2_line> LIKE LINE OF t2.

LOOP AT t2 ASSIGNING <t2_line> WHERE contract = wa_view-num.
  CLEAR: wa_talv-vol_fat_atual
  wa_talv-vol_fat_atual = <t2_line>-kzwi6d.
ENDLOOP.
```

I´ve tried to do:

```
LOOP AT t2 ASSIGNING <t2_line> WHERE contract = wa_view-num.
  CLEAR: wa_talv-vol_fat_atual
  AT LAST.
    SUM.
    wa_talv-vol_fat_atual = <t2_line>-kzwi6d.
  ENDAT.
ENDLOOP.
```

And I get the message:

> "SUM" statement it´s not allowed in an "LOOP ... ASSIGNING ....

What I want is to sum all the values that are in `<t2_line>-kzwi6d` inside of this loop and after that put in the variable `wa_talv-vol_fat_atual`.

I already tried to use `collect` and `sum` statements but I´m getting errors due to the field symbol.

How can I do it right?

Comment: `SUM` should not be used, it's tagged obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
CLEAR: wa_talv-vol_fat_atual
LOOP AT t2 ASSIGNING <t2_line> WHERE contract = wa_view-num.
  ADD <t2_line>-kzwi6d TO wa_talv-vol_fat_atual.
ENDLOOP.
```

ABAP has many constructs to do things, but sometimes it works to just use the simple commands.

This will not be the most efficient approach if this `LOOP` is inside another `LOOP`, e.g. if you really need all the totals for all the different values for `NUM`. But there are other questions and answers out there to help you out with that.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `wa_talv-vol_fat_atual += <t2_line>-kzwi6d` (>= NW 7.54) or `wa_talv-vol_fat_atual = wa_talv-vol_fat_atual + <t2_line>-kzwi6d` (< NW 7.54) instead of `ADD`, as recommended by the [ABAP programming guideline _Use the operator format_](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abencalc_expresssion_guidl.htm).

Comment: I'd suggest using `REDUCE` for summing and not that old stuff anymore.

Comment: Both of your suggestions worked just fine, I have already tried, my problem was the clear inside of the loop statement, it should be outside of the loop. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 3):

This stuff can be done with OpenSQL syntax on internal table for some time now.

```
SELECT SUM( kzwi6d )
FROM @t2 AS t
WHERE contract = @wa_view-num
INTO @wa_talv-vol_fat_atual.
```

No loops, no field symbols. Simple, pure and effective.